# Finding $p$ and $k$ such that $\sin^2\frac{(p-1)\pi}{n}=\sin \frac{(k-1)\pi}{n}\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, numerical-methods

> Let $n$ be a fixed natural number, then find the solution of the following equation for natural numbers $p$ and $k$, where $1\leq p, k\leq 2n$:
> $$\sin^2\frac{(p-1)\pi}{n}=\sin \frac{(k-1)\pi}{n}\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$

I verified that the above equation satisfies for the following pairs $(p,k):$

$$\{(1,1),(2,2),(n+1,n+1),(n+2,2), (2n,2), (n,n)\}.$$

Does this list exhaust all the solutions for the pair $(p,k)$? I am finding it difficult to write an explicit proof. A detailed proof will be of very much help!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why p-1 and k-1? Why not just p and k from 0 to 2n-1?

Comment: Check case $n=12$, there are additional solutions.